# Where would the file be located?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Where would the Default.aspx/OtherNames file be located? I'm trying to find the code for the directory but cant seem to figure out if its within Default.aspx or if its in the same folder as Default.aspx

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetSingleTrackData",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

Code Behind file

```
public partial class Admin_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {

            string email = Request.Form["login-email"];
            string password = Request.Form["login-password"];

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BradConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                //command
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        cmd.CommandText = "select * from admin where email='" + email + "' and pwd='" + password + "'";

                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while(reader.Read())

                        {
                            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx?name=" + reader["fname"].ToString());

                        }


                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: GetSingleTrackData function will be part of Default.aspx.cs file

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan so it would be just code part of that file?

Comment: yes, it will be a code part of that file

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I looked into the file and all I could find was this, so I am confused --->                                                                                                                                           while(reader.Read())
                      
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx?name=" + reader["fname"].ToString());

                        }

                       
                    }
                    catch { }

Comment: can you edit your question to post the cs file, for the ajax request to work the function has to be part of Default.aspx.cs page

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I posted the cs file and oh okay I understand, it looks like that function in the cs page is a loop where the name is inserted

Comment: yes. and the code is posted shows the page name as "Admin_Default" are you sure the page name you mentioned in ajax is proper? is it "Default " or "Admin_Default"?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan oh okay, I am sure the page name is called " Default.aspx.cs" , so I guess the "GetSingleTrackData" function is located in another file? or I guess maybe its actually in the index.hmtl file ?